# Create a Spring bean that cannot be autowired

Tags: java, spring

I have a class A that extends B, which implements C. Currently, A takes B has an input argument and is the only defined bean that is an implementation of C, so it gets autowired whenever C is needed.

Without changing the ALL of the places where C is needed or the class structure of A/B/C, I need make B a defined bean so the same instance can be re-used. The problem is then I have 2 implementations of C (A and B). Is there a way to mark B so that it cannot be autowired?

Current:

```
  <bean id="A" class="A">
    <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="B">
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

Wanted (so same instance of B can be used elsewhere):

```
  <!-- TODO: Somehow mark B so it cannot be autowired -->
  <bean id="B" class="B"/>

  <bean id="A" class="A">
    <constructor-arg ref="B">
  </bean>

  <bean id="Foo" class="Foo">
    <constructor-arg ref="B">
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to eliminate a bean from autowiring, then you can set ***autowire-candidate*** attribute of that bean tag to false.
For example consider your case(Here I am setting B bean's ***autowire-candidate*** attribute to false)

```
 <bean id="B" class="B" autowire-candidate="false"/>

  <bean id="A" class="A">
    <constructor-arg ref="B">
  </bean>

  <bean id="Foo" class="Foo">
    <constructor-arg ref="B">
  </bean>
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You could use qualifiers attached to `@Autowired`.

E.g., if you want to wire the bean with id `B`, you can do the following:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("B")
private C c;
```

Comment: This works but requires me to change it every single place C is used, which is not scalable for my architecture.